# iphone GPS Accuracy value and getting current co-ordinates value

Tags: iphone, gps, compass-geolocation

I am using GPS in my app. The issue it is not getting proper value(I get cached value what i get before. n.can anyone please tell me how to use timestamp to get current value? And i want to show the GPS Accuracy value in Feets. Can anyone please guide me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you may use timestamp to get current value & you can set accuracy also just check apple documentation for this [click here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html) i hop it would be helpful to you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i am struggling how to get the GPS Accuracy level. Please guide me friend.

Comment: @Adhees: Infect apple is also giving only 10 meters of accuracy and one is to try best accuracy but i didn't get best accuracy any time. So it is very difficult to get result in feets so if you get any result in feets then its your luck. Well let me try some thing to get its best result then i'll tell you.
happy codeing :)